# bootstrap-table load problem after load the table dynamically in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table

I have a single page that works fine, page1.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
<main class="p-5" id="main">
    <div class="container-fluid " >
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped caption-top" data-toggle="table" data-url="datos/datos.json">
            <caption class="h1">Datos</caption>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" data-field="user" >User</th>
                <th scope="col" data-field="color">Color</th>                
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

and correctly display the json, datos/datos.json

```
[{"user":"a", "color":"b"},{"user":"c", "color":"d"},{"user":"e", "color":"f"}]
```

The problem is when I try to dynamically load the content of the main, page2.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    ...    
    <script>
        $(function() {

                $( "#main" ).load( "fragments/fragment.html", function() {
                    $('#mytable').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {url: 'datos/datos.json'});
                    $('#mytable').bootstrapTable('refresh', {url: 'datos/datos.json'});
                   
                } );

            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<main class="p-5" id="main">
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

where fragments/fragment.html is

```html
<div class="container-fluid " >
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped caption-top" data-toggle="table" data-url="datos/datos.json">
        <caption class="h1">Datos</caption>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" data-field="user" >User</th>
            <th scope="col" data-field="color">Color</th>                
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

the table does not load the data.

I have tried several things inside the function, but without result

```js
function() {
    $('#mytable').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {url: 'datos/datos.json'});
    $('#mytable').bootstrapTable('refresh', {url: 'datos/datos.json'});
                   
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks